# Python max() function ignoring max if first item of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code which is trying to identify the index of the maximum item in a list. This functions fine until the maximum of 10 appears as the first item of the list where it is ignored.

```
myList = [10,3,7,3,9]
highest = myList.index(max(myList))
print(highest)

#Outputs 4

myList = [3,10,7,3,9]
highest = myList.index(max(myList))
print(highest)

#Outputs 1
```

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I can't seem to work out why it ignores the 10, and only if it's at position 0.

Comment: Are you sure this code produces the output you are describing? I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: No, there's something wrong in your example. Index will return the index of the first match with the exact value

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the code provided.

Comment: If your first list contained strings instead of ints, it would be understandable.

Comment: @khelwood understandable, and expected. Since string comparisons with <,> in python are lexicographic and '9' is > '1'

Comment: @alexanderhurst that's the only thing that I could think it could be, but when the 10 is placed elsewhere in the array, it functions without an issue.

Comment: @HollyBillinghurst That is very strange, no one here has been able to reproduce your issue. Can you provide the python version you are using (run "python -V" to get this info )? Also is this the entire code that you are running? Is there any code any where else in your file? If there is any other code, can we see that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as an answer for additional space and formatting options.
Can you run the following in an empty file and provide the output for me?

```
def list_debugging(myList):
    print("list:", myList)
    print("max:", max(myList))
    print("max index", myList.index(max(myList)))
    maxVal = max(myList)
    print("max var:", maxVal)
    maxIndex = myList.index(maxVal)
    print("max index var:", maxIndex)
    highest = myList.index(max(myList))
    print("index of highest:", highest)
    print()


list_debugging([10, 3, 7, 3, 9])
list_debugging([3, 10, 7, 3, 9])
list_debugging(['10', '3', '7', '3', '9'])
list_debugging(['3', '10', '7', '3', '9'])
```

The output that I got and expect is

```
list: [10, 3, 7, 3, 9]
max: 10
max index 0
max var: 10
max index var: 0
index of highest: 0

list: [3, 10, 7, 3, 9]
max: 10
max index 1
max var: 10
max index var: 1
index of highest: 1

list: ['10', '3', '7', '3', '9']
max: 9
max index 4
max var: 9
max index var: 4
index of highest: 4

list: ['3', '10', '7', '3', '9']
max: 9
max index 4
max var: 9
max index var: 4
index of highest: 4
```

If you get the same output then I believe there is either other code in your program that is causing the problem which we would need to see to fix. Or it is a python interpretter bug (unlikely but possible) in which case I would like to know what python version that you are running so that I could try to reproduce it.